# extjs dynamically add a grid to a tab?

Tags: extjs

In my extjs tabpanel, I have a tab. In the tab I do a :

```
this.tab.add(this.someGrid1);
```

Now based on a certain condition, I want to do :

```
if (cond ==true)
this.tab.remove(this.someGrid1);
this.tab.add(this.someGrid2);
```

Is this possible?
I tried without the remove and it does not work. Nothing happens, the old someGrid1 remains.

EDIT: By taking the suggestions, I changed code  to :

```
if (cond ==true)
this.tab.remove(this.someGrid1);
this.tab.add(this.someGrid2);
this.tab.doLayout();

else if (cond ==false)
this.tab.remove(this.someGrid2);
this.tab.add(this.someGrid1);
this.tab.doLayout();
```

When page loads, `cond == true` and things work good. When I change cond to false through a combo, someGrid1 loads fine.
When I change back to `cond ==true`, the code does not execute beyond

```
this.tab.add(this.someGrid2);
this.tab.doLayout();
```

and someGrid2 is not rendered. The error is this:

```
Error: b.getPositionEl().dom is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding and removing components dynamically at run time, you'll have to make sure that Ext triggers a re-rendering of the component to ensure that the changed state will be reflected. I actually don't know the exact structure of your panel but assuming that `this.tab` is the `Ext.TabPanel` you must do

```
this.tab.doLayout();
```

to re-render the component.

Comment: But when I add this.tab.add(this.someGrid1); the first time, , how come doLayout is not needed? Is it done automatically?

Comment: `doLayout()` is called automatically on the initial rendering of the component. Every change thereafter that changes the HTML representation of the component needs an explicit `doLayout()` call (at least in Ext JS 3.x).

Answer (score 1):

That code looks right to me.  Have you tried debugging and verifying that `this.someGrid1` is set properly when the `remove` method is called?  It's easy to get your `this` scope messed up in Ext.

It shouldn't matter, but you might also try adding `true` as a second argument to `remove`.  This will force Ext to destroy the component, and any dom associated with it will be gone.

Perhaps post some additional code if you still can't get this working, but I bet if you use Firebug and debug this function, the solution will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The dom is destroyed on `remove` so you have to recreate the div. That is why you're getting the `dom is undefined` error message.